# Running spark package in R isn't working, how do I call a spark package into R?

Tags: r, apache-spark, fpgrowth

I'm trying to implement the fp-growth algorithm in R through sparklyr.

I've installed the sparklyr package and called the library sparklyr which works, but when I call the library ml_fpgrowth it's not working.

[image]
The warning message says its not available for my version of R but I believe that's the latest R version.

How else can I install that ml_fpgrowth package?

Answer (score 0):

`ml_fpgrowth()` is a function, not a package.

See documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/1.0.0/topics/ml_fpgrowth).

Just install sparklyr like you do, and then:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(installr)
```

(There is no need to load the functions into R, just the packages)

After you can run your command line (fpm <- ...)

Comment: I get the error: "could not find function :ml_fpgrowth"

Comment: What appears when you lunch this: `library(sparklyr)` ?